# Same Username but Different Domain SPWeb.EnsureUser "User does not exist"

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2019, sharepoint-permissions, spgroup

We have configured 2 different domains (Domain1 & Domain2) for people picker settings. Both domains have some similar users ex. Domain1\TestUser1 & Domain2\TestUser1.

This user is getting resolved from People Picker (Both domains). When i run SPWeb.EnsureUser(Domain2\TestUser1) in PowerShell it throws an Error says "User not found" but SPWeb.EnsureUser(Domain1\TestUser1) is got resolved.

Also when i add the Domain2\TestUser1 to the SharePoint group from the UI it is automatically adding Domain1\TestUser1 but not actual Domain2\TestUser1 user to the SharePoint group.

Can anyone help me to fix this error or how it is happening.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Found this --> EnsureUser fails when there is more than one match. This can happen when: 1) Two users have the same title 2) One user has multiple accounts https://github.com/Microsoft/mattercenter/issues/57

Comment: Thank you @JefinMathew. I found this but is this fixed? or is there any workaround for this issue